# Find/Replace regex to in the first download of html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an html code like this:

```
<a class="on-load-more-page load-more-page next-up grey"
href="https://url/name-link">
<span>Load more...</span> 
</a>
```

and when pulling down then it looks like this:

```
<a class="on-load-more-page load-more-page next-up grey" href="https://url/name-link/page1"> (Here, and it can be up to 100,200 pages) 
<span>Load more...</span>
</a>
```

What should I do to find and replace html for the first download of the content that shows all the content I need to get?

Comment: `<div id="load-more">Load more...</div>` - give it an ID. `$('#load-more').html(...)`

Comment: Sorry, I write missing, can you review and help me?

Comment: Well: what makes you think that you can or should use regular expressions to parse HTML? Rather look out for a real HTML parser!

Comment: @GhostCat, I think maybe you're right, do you have the answer to it? Thank you

Comment: Use SimpleHtmlDom to parse the URL from the link. Plenty of examples in the documentation. https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/